# Displaying a CSV layer and a .shp layer in the same project

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, csv, display

I'm a newbie to GIS and particularly to QGIS. I am using QGIS 3.22.5 on MacOS 12.3.1 Monterey.

I want my project to display two layers. One layer is sourced from a CSV delimited text file. The other layer is sourced from a .shp vector file.

Here's the problem. Whichever data source is imported first is displayed just fine as a Layer. **But** the second data source that is imported is not displayed as a Layer at all.

Here's what I've tried:

- I have switched the order of importing but it makes no difference.
  Only a layer from the first data source is displayed, the second is
  never visible.
- I have unchecked each layer in turn in the Layers panel but it
  doesn't display the layer generated by the data that was imported
  second.
- I have played with the Layer Styling in many ways but have not had
  any success.

How can I make sure that both Layers are displayed in the same Project, irrespective of the order in which the data sources are imported?

Comment: It's likely that this is a variant of our most frequent Question -- how to display data with an incorrect spatial reference. Unfortunately, you need to provide the spatial references and extent envelopes for both layers before we can help.

Comment: Thank you very much , Vince. I shall teach myself how to identify the spatial references and extent envelopes before pursuing a solution to my problem.

Comment: Can you post both the CSV and the Shapefile?